# ActiveRecord Association for has_one & has_many associative table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, models

I'm trying to set up two models, with an associative table between them.  I have defined my model associations as such:

```
class Homebase < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :homebase_addresses
  has_many :addresses, through: :homebase_address
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :homebase_address
  has_one :homebase, through: :homebase_address
end
```

And my association:

```
 class HomebaseAddress < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :homebase
   belongs_to :address
 end
```

My instances create OK:

```
homebase = Homebase.create
address = Address.create
homebase_address = HomebaseAddress.create(homebase: homebase, address: address)
```

However,

```
homebase.addresses
```

gives the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError:
       Could not find the association :homebase_address in model Homebase
```

What am I missing here?  Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find
>   the association :homebase_address in model Homebase

Your problem is in your associations in *Homebase* model. You have `homebase_address` instead of `homebase_addresses`

```
class Homebase < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :homebase_addresses
  has_many :addresses, through: :homebase_addresses
                                          #^^^^^
end
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it!